# receive sails.js messages on model create on a third party domain

Tags: node.js, socket.io, sails.js

I'm trying to workout how to receive messages from sails.js when a new entry is created via the rest api. I'm trying to receive this message outside of sails (but also for other reasons in sails)

In my sails app I can receive the message when a new entry is like so...

```
var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:1337");
    socket.on("connect", function(){
    socket.request("/job", {}, function(jobs){
        console.log("jobs", jobs);
    })  

    socket.on('message', function(message){
        console.log('message', message);
    })
})
```

When a new 'job' is created, the web app receives a message.

I would like to receive the same message outside of sails. I've used this gist https://gist.github.com/epadillas/5993856 as a guide.

Problem is I don't seem to be able to pick up messages. I tried to do the same socket.io("connect") followed by socket.request however it seems that request isn't part of the standard socket.io-client.

Hope this makes sense!

Cheers,

Comment: have you tried changing the socket and session store to use redis? its in `config/sockets.js` and `config/session.js`